# What effect does environmental variable CLUTTER_IM_MODULE have?

Tags: environment-variables, input-method

I knows this can be set like as `CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim`, but I don't know what effect this variable has.

Comment: If you ask me, it just "clutters" up the environment! But then, I don't use [clutter](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/scim-clutter-immodule), so I can't say how it's actually used.